# Passing two parameters into shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sqoop

Im very new shell script. Im ran the below sqoop command in shell script and got the result.

sqoop command in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read table; do
sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb --username root --password cloudera --query "describe $table"
done<tables.txt
```

Input file: tables.txt has just one word: MYTAB And Im gettting result for that.

But how can I write a script to take two parameters from the file when data in tables.txt looks like this: MYDB:MYTAB and I want to pass dbname and table name  to my sqoop command in the script which looks like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read table; do
sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/$dbname --username root --password cloudera --query "describe $table"
done<tables.txt
```

Can anyone tell me how to extract the values from the file and put them in the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `read` statement after setting the proper field separator `IFS` to `:`

```
while IFS=":" read -r dbname table; do
```

Comment: ++ Super fast answer :)

Comment: @anubhava: No way as fast you _sir_! Thanks for the complement!

Comment: It is working. If there are multiple parameters, we can just give 
while IFS=":" read -r dbname table arg3 arg; do and just use them in our commands. This is very clear and thanks !

Comment: @Sidhartha: Happy to be of help!